# How to redirect to a thank-you.html page after form submission (javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using a service called email.js

https://www.emailjs.com/

Here is the script:

````
  ```emailjs
                    .send(
                        "service_qenubp3",
                        "template_htul1w9",
                        templateParams,
                        "FKN-7Z513oHHBUzlm"
                    )
                    .then(
                        function (response) {
                            console.log(
                                "SUCCESS!",
                                response.status,
                                response.text
                            );
                            setEmailSent(true);
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            console.log("FAILED...", error);
                        }
                    );
            };
        };
````

I have a functioning form using their script however there is no from success page redirect option.

I would like to simply redirect using this script:

```
  window.open("https://rococo-kelpie-4411df.netlify.app/thankyou.html
");
}
```

I am having trouble implementing it.

Here is the URL where the form is working (click start here) minus the thank you page.

https://rococo-kelpie-4411df.netlify.app/xindex